# Capture System.Diagnostics.Debug Output in a WCF application

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, slimdx

I have a WCF console application that includes the SlimDX library. SlimDX outputs a log using the 'Write' method of System.Diagnostics.Debug. I am currently not able to view this log in the console. I would like to capture the output from SlimDX and write it to the console.

Here is my implementation so far (not working):

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/users/paulm/documents/output.txt", FileMode.Create);

            Writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Add(new System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener(Writer));
```

This implementation is not capturing the output from SlimDX. Here is SlimDX source code:

```
#include "ObjectTable.h"

#include "InternalHelpers.h"

#include "ComObject.h"



using namespace System;

using namespace System::Text;

using namespace System::Threading;

using namespace System::Globalization;

using namespace System::Collections::ObjectModel;

using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

using namespace System::Diagnostics;



namespace SlimDX

{

    static ObjectTable::ObjectTable()

    {

        m_Table = gcnew Dictionary<IntPtr, ComObject^>();

        m_Ancillary = gcnew Dictionary<IntPtr, List<ComObject^>^>();

        m_SyncObject = gcnew Object();



        AppDomain::CurrentDomain->DomainUnload += gcnew System::EventHandler( OnExit );

        AppDomain::CurrentDomain->ProcessExit += gcnew System::EventHandler( OnExit );

    }



    ObjectTable::ObjectTable()

    {

    }



    void ObjectTable::OnExit( Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e )

    {

        SLIMDX_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(sender);

        SLIMDX_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(e);



        String^ leakString = ReportLeaks();

        Debug::Write( leakString ); // this is the output I would like to capture

    }
```

Any insights as to what I would need to modify wrt WCF in order to capture SlimDX output?

Answer (score 0):

Debug class has a Default Trace Listener if none is specified. So you should be able to see the log in the Output Window of Visual Studio. (Debug->Windows->Output)
However, if you are in Release mode then it will not log to the output window. Try executing the program in Debug mode or add "#define DEBUG" on top of your file and then execute. 
Hope it helps!